# TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of null

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I get this error:

TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of null
NewGroupform._this.onSubmitGroup
src/main/content/apps/chat/components/NewGroupform.js:74

```
      71 |
  }
  72 |
      73 |
      if (!found) members.push({ >
          74 | contact: this.props.user._id,
          |
          ^ 75 | isAdmin: true,
          76 | isModerator: true
          77 |
      })
```

everything works correctly, but when I try to create a group in the chat, when I press send I get this error and I can't find a way to solve it, any help will be well received thanks in advance ..

I don't understand where the error is, can someone help me?
I leave my code:

```
export default class NewGroupform extends Component {
state = {
    admins: [],
    moderators: [],
    groupName: '',
    mood: "",
    groupImage: false,
    preview: {},
    type: "public",
    isPrivate: false,
    members: [],
    loading: false,
    success: {
        status: false,
        msg: "",
    },
    errors: {
        status: false,
        msg: "",
        name: ""
    }

}

onSubmitGroup = (e) => {
        /// Handel form submition
        e.preventDefault()
            //set loader
        this.setState({
            loading: true,
        })

        let {
            groupName,
            mood,
            isPrivate,
            members
        } = this.state

        // add current user whose created the group as admin for group members
        // and parse members array
        let found = false
        const membersLength = members.length

        for (let i = 0; i < membersLength; i++) {
            const member = members[i]
            if (member.contact === this.props.user._id) {
                members[i].isAdmin = true
                members[i].isModerator = true
                found = true
            }
        }

        if (!found) members.push({
            contact: this.props.user._id,
            isAdmin: true,
            isModerator: true
        })

        let data = {
            name: groupName,
            avatar: '',
            mood,
            isPrivate,
            status: 'online',
            members,
            dialog: []
        }
```

I leave the entire code in the pastebin: https://pastebin.com/Y3X0uzGH

Comment: Simply `this.props.user` is not defined.

Comment: Thanks for the answer could help define, thanks

Comment: Where is the data for ‘this.props.user’ coming from? Is there a parent component responsible for that? Try setting defaultProps in NewGroupForm with some sample data and see what happens. Or check the parent component to see why ‘user’ is null.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, they have given me the code like this and is the only thing wrong as I should define it?